# trying to make a vertically and diagonally check in tic tac toe

Tags: c#

here's what I have as the horizontally, but I'm having a hard time tryna figure out the other too, it would be Appreciative if someone could help

```
    public Boolean CheckForWinnerRowsColsDiagonals() 
    {
        isDone = false; //assume this to start
        PlayerWon = true; //assume this too
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
        {
            if (!gameGrid[x, 0].Equals('N'))
            {
                if (gameGrid[x, 0] == gameGrid[x, 1] && gameGrid[x, 0] == gameGrid[x, 2])
                {
                    isDone = true;
                    if (gameGrid[x, 0].Equals('O'))
                    {
                        PlayerWon = false;
                    }
                    return isDone;
                }
            }
        }
        return isDone;
    }
```

i've tried trying the x to y to get a better understanding and switching the numbers around from (y, 0) (y, 1) (y, 0) (y, 2)

to

(y, 1) (y, 1) (y, 2) (y, 2)

if (gameGrid[x, 0] == gameGrid[x, 1] && gameGrid[x, 0] == gameGrid[x, 2])

although I'm having a hard time on trying to figure it out. but could someone explain

Comment: Diagonals are (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (0,2) (1,1) (2, 0)

Comment: Your code does not compile.  Please show where _all_ your variables including properties and fields are defined.  This will help us help you.  [mcve]